# I tried to build a IPV6 DNS website on respberrypi but not working

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi, ipv6

Im new here. not sure if my question is too newbee.
I am building a website on my raspberry (for testing). here are my steps:
1. get my raspberry's IPV6 from my router
2. in free dns provider, point a domain to this IPV6 (AAAA)
3. in raspberrypi, make a index.html and start  SimpleHTTPServer

However, when I trid to access such domain, it says connection refused.
I am not sure which step is wrong.
Could someone please leave some comments?

Regards
Xing

Answer (score 0):

The standalone mode of SimpleHTTPServer in Python 2 only supports IPv4. Notice how it says "Serving HTTP on **0.0.0.0**"; that indicates it uses an IPv4 socket and cannot accept IPv6 connections.

(If it were the opposite – an IPv6 socket bound to [::] – it actually could accept both kinds of connections, unless the program requested otherwise.)

You should use a more reliable HTTP server (there are many, but traditional Apache or Nginx is a good start) and always make sure it is listening on an IPv6 address (usually `::`).